# How to reset a mongoid 3 database connection

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3, moped

In Mongoid 2.x one could execute `Mongoid.database.connection.close` to reset a database connection. This specific API is no longer available in Mongoid3, what is the new way to reset a connection?

Motivation: interrupting a query while it's in-progress (ctrl-c) will kill your connection. Any subsequent queries will just hang. Additionally, thrown errors such as timeouts will do the same thing (see: http://simple10.com/rescuing-from-racktimeout-to-close-mongodb-connection).

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Connection#disconnect-instance_method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
Mongoid::Sessions.default.disconnect
```

or

```
Model.collection.database.session.disconnect
```

This will properly reset the connection if you `ctrl-c` to interrupt a query in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Mongoid3's replacement mongo driver, Moped, actually handles retrying connections automatically.

https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/master/lib/moped/node.rb#L115

Comment: Hmm, if I `ctrl-c` a mongoid query on the console, I can't seem to get it back.  Have to exit the console and restart.  Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: If you're on mongoid 2.x you can call `Mongoid.database.connection.close` to have it reconnect.

Comment: but how does one access a Moped Node instance?

Answer (score 0):

Besides disconnecting a specific session with

`Mongoid::Sessions.default.disconnect`

You can also disconnect all sessions with

`Mongoid::Sessions.disconnect`

You can get a list of all active sessions with

`Mongoid.sessions`